# Randomly primary Constraint violation while inserting datas

Tags: oracle, primary-key, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am inserting many rows (about 200 rows) in a Oracle database. The sql script (which I generated from Ruby) looks a like this :

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID, COL_1, COL_2, COL_3) VALUES (MY_TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, VAL_1, VAL_2,VAL_3);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID, COL_1, COL_2, COL_3) VALUES (MY_TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, VAL_1, VAL_2,VAL_3);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID, COL_1, COL_2, COL_3) VALUES (MY_TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, VAL_1, VAL_2,VAL_3); 
     ....
```

When I run this script in oracle sqlDeveloper, I have randomly primary constraint violations on certain rows. If I relaunch the script with these lines, I have no more errors. 
I tried to insert commits every 100 lines but still have the same error.

What is the cause of that error? I want to import all these lines without those constraint violations, how can I properly import those rows in Oracle?

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: What are unique / primary keys on the table?

Comment: Can you more specific about your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What values does my_table_seq.nextval generate? If it generates values lower than existing values in my_table.id you can run into this kind of problems.

To test this:

```
select max(id) from my_table;

select my_table_seq.nextval from dual;
```

If the sequence generates numbers below the max(ID) in the table you can recreate the sequence with a high enough start value:

```
drop sequence my_table_seq;
create sequence my_table_seq start with 123;
```

Comment: my_table_seq.nextval generates values between 1 and 9999999999999999999999999999. Ok, I see what may cause the problem. I tried to run the sql you provide but Oracle returns ORA-02287 :Sequence not allowed here